# NoMethodError (undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f964a22d7f0>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

We recently updated rails application to Rails `5.0` and are getting this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f964a22d7f0>):
```

if we have the below parameter

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"first name", "middle_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"lname", "email"=>"name@domain.com", "id"=>"138755"} permitted: false>
```

accessing by the both ways works

```
params[:first_name]
params['first_name']
```

Any help on why the error is happening and how to fix it would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you call your params only as symbols `params[:first_name]` does it fix the problem ?

Comment: yes it works as expected and I am able to fetch values

Comment: if your issue is not resolved, can you attach screenshot so that community can have better look at problem?. This is happening because **ActionController::Parameters does not inherit Hash since Rails 5.0**

Comment: Why would you need to symbolize keys for a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`?